# Infinite loop when working with react and react-firebase-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am working with a navigation bar that should be able to switch between multiple chat rooms using react and react-firebase-hooks. (https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks)

However, the chat room will infinitely re-render itself when I choose a room in nav-bar.

I initially thought this is a router issue, but having each rooms sharing the same url, the issue persists.

Right now, when I choose a room using the nav bar, it will send that room number back to App.js using a callback function. App.js will pass that room number to ChatRoom.js, which will get the data from firestore, and re-render itself.

I struggled for several days trying to find anything that could cause the infinite loop with minimal success. Any help would be appreciated!

ChatRoom.js

```js
import React, { useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { useCollectionData, useDocument, useDocumentData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import firebase, { firestore, auth } from '../Firebase.js';
import ChatMessage from './ChatMessage';


const ChatRoom2 = (props) => {

    console.log("chat room rendered");
    
    function saveQuery(){
        const channelid= props.channelid;
        const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages').doc(channelid).collection('chats');
        const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limitToLast(25);
        return [messagesRef,query];
    }

    var returnedVal = useMemo(()=>saveQuery , [props.channelid]);
    const messagesRef = returnedVal[0];
    const query = returnedVal[1];

    const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
    const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState('');
    
    const sendMessage = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(messagesRef);
        console.log(query);
        console.log(messages);

        const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;
        
        await messagesRef.add({
            text: formValue,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            uid,
            photoURL
        })

        setFormValue('');
    }
    return (<>
        <main>
            {messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}
        </main>

        <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>

            <input value={formValue} onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)} placeholder="say something nice" />

            <button type="submit" disabled={!formValue}>️</button>

        </form>
    </>)
}


export default ChatRoom2;
```

ChatList.js (nav bar)

```
const ChatList = (props) => {

    console.log("list rendered");
    const query = firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('strangers').orderBy('channelID').limitToLast(10);
    //console.log(query);
    const [channelidArr] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });

    return (
        <div>
            {channelidArr && channelidArr.map(channelid =>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={() => props.parentCallback(channelid.channelID)}>{channelid.channelID}</button>
                    
                    <br />
                </div>)}

        </div>

    );
};

export default ChatList;
```

App.js

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

//import './App.css';

import firebase, { firestore, auth } from './Firebase.js';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

import ChatList from './components/ChatList.js';
import FindNew from './components/FindNew.js';
import Footer from './components/Footer.js';
import Profile from './components/Profile.js';
import ChatRoom2 from './components/ChatRoom2.js';
import SignOut from './components/SignOut.js';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn.js';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp.js';
import ChatRoom from './components/ChatRoom.js';


function App() {
  console.log('App rendered');
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [roomNum, setRoomNum] = useState([]);

  const callbackFunction = (childData) => {
      setRoomNum(childData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>⚛️</h1>
        <SignOut auth={auth} />
      </header>

      <BrowserRouter >
        <Footer />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/profile">
            <Profile />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/new">
            <FindNew />
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/signup">
            {() => {
              if (!user) {
                return <SignUp />;
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            }}
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/direct">
            {user ?
              <div>
                <ChatList parentCallback={callbackFunction} />
                <ChatRoom2 channelid={roomNum} />
              </div> : <SignIn />}
          </Route>
        

        </Switch>

      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you tell which component is render looping? Have you tried simplifying your code even more to isolate which component/hook usage is triggering the render looping?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. the chat room component is causing the infinite loop, the sequence of event happened is: App render -> chat list renders -> chat room renders ->chat list renders -> chat room renders infinitely.  In the chunk.js file, it says 
 " const {
    channelid
  } = props.channelid; " is causing the error. I'm new with react and I'm sorry if certain things i say are not making any sense.

Comment: It's probably difficult to create a running codesandbox with this code (you could try though). Few thoughts. (1) What if you used the `useCollectionDataOnce` hook in the chatroom component? (2) If you comment out the `const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });` in chatroom does it still render-loop? Can you include a more complete `app.js` component so we can see how the callback and `roomNum` value is maintained.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying again! I tried your suggestions.1) using useCollectionDataOnce hook in chatroom also causes infinite loop. 2) removing useCollectionData does not cause infinite loop. 3) I updated App.js which now includes the callback function and roomNum state.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I suspect it could be caused by `query` being redeclared each render cycle and that `query` ends up being a `useCollectionData` hook dependency (I've dug through the source code and I *think* this is the case). Try using a `useMemo` hook to memoize the `query` value with a dependency on the `channelid` prop so `query` is a stable reference value for the `useCollectionData` hook.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying again! I tried you suggestions and it seems like react is not happy with using use the `useCollectionData` hook inside `useMemo`. and I am also a bit confused since `useCollectionData` should listen to the changes made in firestore, if I put it inside `useMemo` and have it dependent on channelid, doesn't it only gets called and re-renders when I switch channel and doesn't re-render if the firestore is update?

Comment: Nono, leave the `useCollectionData` hook where it is, just try memoizing the `query` value, so the first 3 lines.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is now not causing any infinite loop and working wonderfully. On on side note, I noticed that the variables that I moved into useMemo has became not accessible even when I declare them outside of function scope, is there a way that I make those variables global? I updated the chatroom.js file and the three `console.log` are producing `undefined`.  (I suspect message is undefined because query is.) Again, thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Try `const [messagesRef, query] = useMemo(() => saveQuery() , [props.channelid]);`. You basically aren't actually calling your `saveQuery` function. [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue Summary

`useCollectionData` memoizes on the `query` parameter but since a new `query` *reference* was declared each render cycle the firebase hook was rerun and updated collection and rerendered the component.

```
const { channelid } = props;
const messagesRef = firestore
  .collection('messages')
  .doc(channelid)
  .collection('chats');
const query = messagesRef // <-- new query reference
  .orderBy('createdAt')
  .limitToLast(25);

const [messages] = useCollectionData(
  query, // <-- reference update trigger hook
  { idField: 'id' },
);
```

## Solution

`query` has only a dependency on the `channelid` prop value, so we can memoize the `query` value and pass a stable value reference to the `useCollectionData` hook.

```
const { channelid } = props;

const query = useMemo(() => {
  const messagesRef = firestore
    .collection('messages')
    .doc(channelid)
    .collection('chats');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limitToLast(25);
  return query;
}, [channelid]);

const [messages] = useCollectionData(
  query,  // <-- stable reference
  { idField: 'id' },
);
```